# Twitter Bootstrap - Navbar toggle won't open on pages other than the index

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been experimenting with Bootstrap 3 on my site here: http://infenterprises.com/
My problem is, when I attempt to open the navbar toggle (mobile view) It only opens on the Home page. It does this with the services drop-down as-well.

Thank you!

```
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://infenterprises.com/">INFENTERPRISES</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="http://infenterprises.com/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../about/">About</a></li>
                         <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects<span class="caret">             </span>                         
                            </a><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>

                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="../services/">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a   href="../contact/">Contact</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a 404 error pointing to the wrong resource in your console. If you didn't know, you can check this through the 'Inspect Element' option when you right-click on the page.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://infenterprises.com/about/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js

Check the link to make sure you have this correct. As a guess: Try using the root absolute path instead of a relative path. e.g. `<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I had to do that with some other elements and completely disregarded the jQuery path. Thank you for providing me with a solution aswell as how you got to it!